# Xss Vulnerability

Tags: java, jsp, xss

I have make an audit with Acunetix Vulnerability Scanner about my web application, the Developer Reporttell me that:

```
/referentiels-web/j_spring_cas_security_check
Details
URL encoded GET input ticket was set to ST-1664-V7HlBALHdSMeqYmAjHL9-passeport01.brgm-rec.fr'"()&%<acx><ScRiPt>qvVq(9803)</ScRiPt>
>qvVq(9803)</ScRiPt>
GET /referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05ECF865408DAC009A0DAF HTTP/1.1
Referer: https://myapp.com:443/referentiels-web/
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21
Accept: */*
Host: Rgf-ref.brgm-rec.fr
```

but when 
when I try to reproduce this xss vulnerabilities, 
I can not reproduce, why ..?

***My test url:***

```
https://myapp.com:443/referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05EC‌​F865408DAC009A0DAF?<sc ript>alert('test')</sc ript>
```

***The report:***
[image]

***Postman:***
[image]

***authfailed.jsp:***

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login to CAS failed!</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Login to CAS failed!</h2>

<font color="red">
    Your CAS credentials were rejected.<br/><br/>
    Reason: <%= ((AuthenticationException) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION)).getMessage() %>
</font>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, let's start with **how** you are trying to reproduce

Comment: @cricket_007 i have do this `https://myapp.com:443/referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05ECF865408DAC009A0DAF?<sc ript>alert('test')</sc ript>`

Comment: And you typed that into the URL bar? I don't think that is an XSS because the script tag isn't evaluated by your site

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i typed that into my URL bar

Comment: @cricket_007 the report say XSS

Comment: You need to use a HTTP tool like Postman to set HTTP parameters to `ST-1664-V7HlBALHdSMeqYmAjHL9-passeport01.brgm-rec.fr'"()&%<acx><ScRiPt>qvVq(9803)</ScRiPt>
>qvVq(9803)</ScRiPt>` you can't just give the script tag to the URL because that's not what the tool said the problem was because the URL was only a GET request to `/referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05ECF865408DAC009A0DAF`

Comment: @cricket_007 With  Postman I can not reproduce :(

Comment: Can you include screenshot of the Postman request?

Comment: @cricket_007 i have update my post

Comment: You need to use the Params button on the right of the URL, not the Headers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105285/discussion-between-mercer-and-cricket-007).

Comment: @cricket_007 
ok and in the param 
What should I put in value and key

Comment: Long story short, **it's a bad idea to show stack traces to users, please don't do it**. It's bad for UX (it makes your site look clunky and broken), it doesn't help users (users don't read error messages), and on the security side, it reveals unnecessary details about your system and in this case, it is vulnerable to XSS because you echo back an exception message, which probably contains bits of unsanitised user input.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the report that the Script is set into the "ticket" GET input

Try using this url:

```
https://myapp.com:443/referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05EC‌​F865408DAC009A0DAF?ticket=ST-1664-V7HlBALHdSMeqYmAjHL9-passeport01.brgm-rec.fr'"()&%<ScRiPt>alert('test')</ScRiPt>
```

or an encoded one like:

```
https://myapp.com:443/referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05EC‌​F865408DAC009A0DAF?ticket=%53%54%2D%31%36%36%34%2D%56%37%48%6C%42%41%4C%48%64%53%4D%65%71%59%6D%41%6A%48%4C%39%2D%70%61%73%73%65%70%6F%72%74%30%31%2E%62%72%67%6D%2D%72%65%63%2E%66%72%27%22%28%29%26%25%3C%53%63%52%69%50%74%3E%61%6C%65%72%74%28%27%74%65%73%74%27%29%3C%2F%53%63%52%69%50%74%3E
```

or

```
https://myapp.com:443/referentiels-web/authfailed.jsp;jsessionid=83A16DB68D05EC‌​F865408DAC009A0DAF?ticket=U1QtMTY2NC1WN0hsQkFMSGRTTWVxWW1BakhMOS1wYXNzZXBvcnQwMS5icmdtLXJlYy5mciciKCkmJTxTY1JpUHQ+YWxlcnQoJ3Rlc3QnKTwvU2NSaVB0Pg==
```